# Is there a general way to specify elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a general way to specify elements in jQuery. For example using the `$(this).find` or next function.

I am trying to create a button that when copied will only activate one at a time.

At the moment when the button is duplicated output is copied.

See example.

http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/12/

```
<a href="#" class="vote-btn">button</a>
<p class="vote-number">+ 70,101</p> <a href="#" class="vote-btn">button</a>
<p class="vote-number">+ 70,101</p> <a href="#" class="vote-btn">button</a>
<p class="vote-number">+ 70,101</p>


$(".vote-number").hide();
$(".vote-btn").click(function () {
    $(".vote-number").finish().show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Comment: `"For example using the $(this).find or next function."`... why the hell don't you try them and see what happens!!!

Comment: thanks for your help guys. i am trying to change the html but it now doesnt work. can you help http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/18/

Comment: Why would you expect it to work when you change the html like that? Do you even understand what `next` does as to why it work in the provided answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".vote-number").finish()` will target all the elements with the class `vote-number`. Instead, you want to target only the element next to the button. So, use `$(this).next(".vote-number")` to target specifically.

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/13/)***

```
$(".vote-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".vote-number").finish().show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. i am trying to change the html but it now doesnt work. can you help http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/18/

Comment: @user2965875 you have reversed the order. So, instead of `next()`, use `prev()`. http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/19/

Answer (score 1):

You can do with [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) as using `.vote-btn` will only target the first occurrance of the same, so better use `$(this).next(".vote-number')` which targets to the next `<p>` with class `vote-number`

```
$(".vote-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".vote-number").finish().show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(".vote-btn").click(function(){
  $(this).next('.vote-number').finish().show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8AYd/15/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".vote-number").hide();

$(document).on("click", ".vote-btn", function (e) {
    $(this).prev(".vote-number").show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/X8AYd/20/)***